# Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't recognize Graphic Chip in Intel Celeron G540T

Tags: drivers, resolution, cpu

I want to use Ubuntu and get away from Windows.

I have bought a new Fujitsu TS ESPRIMO Q510 mini PC a few days ago. But its integrated CPU isnt properly recognized by Ubuntu 12.10. The screen resolution is very low and in settings i can only switch between 2x 4:3 format resolutions. But i have a Full HD 16:9 Display.

If i choose 12.04 the resolution is correct and the screen looks fine but i still have some tearing and kind of stuttering if i scroll down, especially in firefox.

This is the CPU: http://ark.intel.com/products/53417/intel-celeron-processor-g540t-2m-cache-2_10-ghz

I think the Intel HD2000 is build in and working here, correct? This chip is often used in many other CPU i think so i cant understand why the latest ubuntu version skips the support for this chip?

Any solution for this? Im not the Terminal geek so it would be nice if there is a easy solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Then reboot

If that gives you problems, then enter the below command to remove it and again, reboot your PC.

`sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`